# How to connect to Coral Dev Board without USB connection

Tags: google-coral

I have a person detection model running in my Google Dev Board which is exposed as a Flask application.

I have enabled direct wifi connection in the Dev board as per coral documentation.

When the Dev board is connected via USB (OTG) cable I am able to access the application using the following URL

http://192.168.100.2:4664

When I disconnect the USB (OTG) connection, I am not able to access this URL in my laptop which is connected to the same wifi network

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard ssh linux tool to connect to the board. Matterfact, mdt is just a friendly wrapper around ssh.

On your host machine, do this and just keep typing enter:

```
host# ssh-keygen
```

It should generate a file `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` that is an rsa key. Copy that key, char by char, log back into the board, create a file in `/home/mendel/.ssh/authorized_keys` and paste the key there.
Then get the ip address on the board using `ip addr` on `wlan0` interface, for instance, mine looks like this:

```
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 3000
...
    inet 192.168.0.160/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
...
```

that is all, just do this to log in with the address you found, for me it is:

```
ssh mendel@192.168.0.160
```

More on ssh: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/

Comment: Hi Nam Vu, Thanks for your response. I have no issues with the above steps and it work fine. But my problem was, when I disconnect the USB-OTG cable. I am no longer able to access the IP from any other device connected in the same wifi network.

Comment: really? How did you set up the flask application? It should be board casted as `0.0.0.0:4664` on the board and you access it via the wlan0 ip address, not 192.168.100.2, what's the usb address only